# Chamar método de outra classe

Tags: java

sou iniciante em java, e estou criando um CRUD básico de uma biblioteca, como tenho muitas operações, achei melhor fazer uma classe especializada pra cada operação, que vai chamar os métodos da classe biblioteca.
Estou fazendo a classe da operação cadastrar, onde ela terá irá chamar os métodos cadastrarAutor, cadastrarLivro, cadastrarAutora da classe biblioteca.

porém não sei como chamar os métodos, pois eles estão em uma classe diferente.

segue o código:

**Classe biblioteca**

```
public void cadastarAutor(Autor autor) {
    this.autores.add(autor); 


}

public void cadastrarEditora(Editora editora) {
    this.editora.add(editora);

}

public void cadastrarLivro(Livro livro) {
    this.livro.add(livro);
}
```

**Classe Cadastrar**

```
import RepositorioLivros.Biblioteca;

  public class Cadastrar {

    Biblioteca biblioteca= new Biblioteca();

    biblioteca.
```

}

como eu vou chamar os métodos da classe biblioteca para usar na classe Cadastrar?, instanciei uma biblioteca na classe cadastrar e já tentei fazer deste modo: **biblioteca.** e chamar os métodos, mas quando eu tento chamar ñ funciona, o Eclipse nem sequer mostra as opçoes após o **.(ponto)**

O correto seria quando eu tentasse chamar, aparecer as opções dos métodos que estão na classe biblioteca, mas Ñ aparece, após eu digitar **biblioteca.** , ele da um erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que ocorre quando tenta chamar?

Comment: editei e coloquei a imagem do erro  na minha pergunta, atualiza e reveja

Comment: `import RepositorioLivros.Biblioteca;`: tem um pacote chamado `RepositorioLivros`?

Comment: sim Igor Venturelli tem sim

Comment: Cadastrar  é para ser um classe ou um método?

Comment: Qual pacote a classe `Cadastrar` está?

Comment: Edita a pergunta incluindo o código completo das duas classes, por favor. Desde a primeira linha do arquivo até a última

Comment: Como eu disse, eu fiz uma classe separadamente pra cada operação, a classe operação vai tratar só das operações da cadastrar, porém as operações estão na classe Biblioteca, e quero chamar elas pra classe Cadastrar....                                                                                                    A classe Cadastrar está em um pacote chamado Operacoes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O corpo da classe pode conter **somente** declarações de membros da classe, como

- campos
- interfaces
- métodos
- inicializadores de instâncias
- inicializadores estáticos
- declarações de construtores para a classe

Para chamar algum método da classe `Biblioteca`, defina um método dentro da classe `Cadastrar` e utilize a instância de `Biblioteca` juntamente com a notação em ponto.

```
public class Cadastrar {
    // ...
    public void meuMetodo() {
        biblioteca.cadastrarAutor(...);
    }
}
```

Leia mais sobre o corpo da classe em Java [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6).

Comment: Obrigado amigo era exatamente isso